# Integral of Product of modified Bessel function, exponential functions and power function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am trying to evaluate the definite integral [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UuZ3.png) to obtain a closed-form solution, with z being the integration variable, and the other parameters are real positive constants.

[image]

The integral can be solved with the aid of Taylor series and variable transform (I guess), however, I am trying to avoid using infinite series solutions. I also tried integration by parts as in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtfAg.png), dv can easily yield the gamma function, but the difficulties come with the blue part (u).

[image]

Can anyone advise on a solution? Special functions are very welcomed.